# Time, hours, periods

Tags: time

Could anybody say me how to write periods of time in English. For example, I know how to say in case of years: from one year to another year. But how to deal with hours. Is it the same? from 5 am to 6 pm or till 6 pm?

Comment: If you look at  [How to express day time range](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/206182), you will find you are not supposed to ask the question above, because a number of people who are able to vote to close questions believe it is general reference.

Comment: Also, if you look at [What's the correct way to format a date range, time range, and days of week in a single line?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107197), you will find you are not supposed to ask the question above, because a number of people who are able to vote to close questions believe it “does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center”.  Why [How to write date range succinctly and unambiguously in American written English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/57606) didn't get closed on either basis is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either approach. You sleep from 12 AM to 7 AM. You work from 8:30 AM till 5:30 PM. The word "till" is just a shortened version of "until", so if you work from 8:30 AM till 5:30 PM, you probably also relax at home from 5:30 PM until you go back to work the next day. It's all correct, though generally people would only use "until" or "till" when talking about time frames on the same day (like, "Today I work from 8:30 AM till 5:30 PM,").

Comment: Just one nit to pick: [Till is not "just a shortened version of 'until'"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until).

Comment: @R Mac. *Till* is not a shortened version of *until*. See the usage note here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/till